# C# combobox change all text items without change index

Tags: c#, combobox

I have combobox with text (17 items). After get results from my mysql i want to change in combobox: "id" ==> "id(1)".

I'm using ComboBox.SelectedIndex, so it cant change it.

I tried this code:

```
CobmoBox.Items.Clear();
for (int h = 0; h < fieldname.Length; h++)
{
    comboBox4.Items.Add(fieldname[h] + "(" + number[h, 0] + ")");
}
```

It is changing text of combobox, but i cant select item... (it shows and disapeare - combobox.text is empty)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change.  Your code is clearing the list, then adding a bunch of items.

Comment: In your code above, you clear `ComboBox` but add to `comboBox4`. Not sure what `number[h,0]` is either. You'll have to give a bit more context and code I guess.

Comment: hmm...this are string[]: fieldname {"id", "name", "second_name", "mail", etc.} and number[number_of_fieldname, 0] = count records;
I want to change text visible to user (dropdown list and selected item on combobox) and i want to chande all items (id => id(count_records) etc.)
Help me pls, ang give some code... I'm begginer

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not understanding the selections and what's what.
Have a look at this article [Understanding SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, SelectedItem & DisplayMemberPath + Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele) (fair disclosure: I wrote it).
It'll show you how to show different text for different items and more.
You can download the code and play with it, It'll give you a good direction for what you want to achieve.

From what I gather, you want to edit the DisplayMember for your SelectedItem, and again, I talk about it in that article

Comment: Thanks for reply :) but i've never heard about MainWindow.xaml.cs and other (for me difficult) things. I'm learning C# - and i cant use your tutorial :( I want to change only Display Member (text) of every item in combobox... isnt there anything easier (like: ComboBox1.item[4].Text = "")

Comment: You don't care about the main window and the rest.  You do care about understanding what you have (items), which is selected, what index is that selection, and what do you display for the selected item.  There's a learning curve when you start something new, and this is part of it. :)

Comment: I understand what i want to change - text of dropdown items and selected item text (the same as in dropdown list), but i dont know how to use it... i tried with dataSource, but it doesnt works...